# I SENT ETH TO WRONG ADDRESS

Tags: ether, addresses

I sent eth to wrong address by accident thru and exchange hitbtc 2. It whats a mistyped attempt so it is considered a "fresh" or unclaimed account. Is there any way around this? if so im up for suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you send eth to an account that does not belong to anyone, the eth is lost forever.

Answer (score 0):

There is no realistic way to get it back, when you are not very fast.

When you are fast, you could publish another transfer of all your balance to another account you own and make sure to set a high gas price. When your frist transaction isnt added to the block chain yet, it may be that the new transaction will be first in the block chain and because you then have a balance of 0, nothing can be transferred anymore. However this is not guaranteed, even when you're fast (at least it's impossible to guarantee when you control less than 51% of the mining power). After a few confirmations/following blocks it will be practically impossible.

It is not possible to get access to another account you don't know the secret key for. The address is derived from the public key, which is derived from the private key, not the other way round. One can't distinguish between a "owned" account where someone sent ether to the frist time and a random one where someone sent it accidentally. You own the account by knowing the private key to the address, so you can sign transaction for it. It is impossible to guess a valid private key (like 1 in 2^160).